# Gitolite with Gitblit integration, is it possible? How?

Tags: git, gitolite, gitblit

is there a way to integrate Gitolite with [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/), so that  [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)  can be used as a viewer and for Https access and Gitolite for fine grained access control(i.e. auth) and ssh+git access

```
   Gitolite ---> ssh+git/ACL ..
   GitBlit ---> https/viewer
```

... [And ya i don't want to believe this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitblit/cVGpx8gfHnM)

Answer (score 0):

There answer here is the same as the answer in your link.  Possible - of course.  Is it implemented?  No.  Will it be?  No.  Gitblit will eventually get native SSH support.

Comment: if a full integration is not possible will there be a problem if i use the same repo forlder/path for the two.     (i.e. you may get a different ACL while using either of them as the changes don't propagate). so for web access you will use GitBlit and for ssh you will use Gitolite but the same repo for both but different access levels.

Comment: You can configure Gitblit's repository directory to match Gitolite and they can share the same repositories.  ACLs of course will be different.